# How to find dependand JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying [Jquery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html) element.In code I can see following import and references

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="../../jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../demos.css">
```

I copied all files mentioned above in my folder and changed path to

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>

    <script src="jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demos.css">
```

But it looks like some css is missing
[image]
How can I find the dependent JS and CSS (Without reading complete JS and CSS source) ?

Comment: Don't use jQuery? Solves my problems.

Comment: @Raynos: What a stupid suggestion.

Comment: @Raynos not a script problem but a missing style issue.

Comment: @ThiefMaster the alternative is serving 70kb of junk for simple auto complete functionality? No thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the module from http://jqueryui.com/download ticking the appropriate boxes, this will deliver a single minified js file (and the required jquery library) as well as a directory containing all the (theme specific) CSS you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion it filtered out many files :) My project structure is pretty different from the source I downloaded. So is there any way to find out all files and place them n single folder ?

Comment: You just need to include the jquery library, the jquery-ui-whaterver-min.js and the <theme_name>\jquery-ui-whaterver.css (from the \js and \css directories in the zip download) - you can include them in the page from wherever you like

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the element to see what styles/classes have been applied to the element which looks wrong.

Do the same thing with the working demo.

You will see what you are missing.